# iOS VAST XML Parser

Tags: ios, objective-c, vast

I have a problem which is how can I play VAST video format in Objective-C? I tried this code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ad3.liverail.com/?LR_PUBLISHER_ID=1331&LR_CAMPAIGN_ID=229&LR_SCHEMA=vast3"];
player.movieSourceType =MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

MPMoviePlayerController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[player prepareToPlay];
self.myPlayer = controller; //Super important
controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds; //Set the size

[self.view addSubview:controller.view]; //Show the view
[controller play]; //Start playing
```

But I've seen only black blank screen. In my opinion I have to parse these links but I can't do it. How can we parse VAST XML parser with using only Apple frameworks, not 3rd party library?

Comment: The Responses seems to be a XML, so NSXMLParser?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work Larme.

Comment: If you put one of the link in of the XML for your `MPMoviePlayerController`, does one of them work?

Comment: if is it possible, can you share sample code. Because i've tried it i can not be success

Comment: https://github.com/denivip/ios-vast-player ? Do you know how VAST work?

Comment: I can not use 3rd Party Library. I found it but i can not use. :/ I tried to understand how does it work..